# Trouble Making executable .jar file

Tags: java, cmd, manifest, executable-jar, manifest.mf

I am trying to make an executable .jar file.  I have been all over the internet trying to figure out how to do this from command prompt.

I have a .class file, a .jar file, a .java file, A Manifest.mf file, and a manifest.txt file.

The most common way I've found online is using -jar -cvfm but I get the following message:

```
Unrecognized option: -cvfe
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

If someone could please provide step-by-step instruction.  Also, I am new to this, so if you use "Package.MainClass", please explain what is means.  Everything is in one file, not multiple files.

I am using Java 9.0.1 for jdk and 9.0.4 for jre.

Comment: Are you running "java -jar -cvfm" or "jar -cvfm"?

Comment: You are confusing things.  "java -jar.." is not the same command as "jar -cvfe".   You might find https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/ useful.

Comment: @ Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Thanks, I would mark your comment as an answer.  I thought I tried that, but I guess I didn't :(

Comment: @TakeThat101 Made an answer out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing things. `java -jar..` is not the same command as  `jar -cvfe`.

You might find https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/ useful.